# Set header to choose app to open pdf from browser

Tags: android, spring, android-intent, http-headers

In my web app the user can download a pdf file.

On PC there is no problem, pdf file opened on browser and then you can choose some action, download or print etc.

So I'm trying with tablet, and I would that when I click download appears the menu to choose which app use to open pdf file, or the default one if there is.

This is my method to download file and in it I set the header:

```
public static HttpEntity<byte[]> downloadPdfFile(final String fileName, final byte[] item){

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
        header.setContentLength(item.length);

        return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(item, header);
    }
```

**UPDATE**
If in my URL I add for example `fileName.pdf` before to download it the menu to choose which app use appears..

So I add this `intent filter` in my app to show it into menu:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf"/>
            </intent-filter>
              
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

But my app there isn't in menu.

Have you any idea?

Comment: What you have seems fine. What is your specific problem on the tablet?

Comment: The problem is that with this header the file has downloaded but no menù to choose which app use to open the file appears

Comment: Did you tap on the notification to bring up a PDF viewer? Do you have PDF viewers installed on the tablet? Have you tried downloading PDFs from elsewhere on this tablet? Do you have a public URL that we can try that is set up using your approach?

Comment: yes I have a pdf view, and I have my app that can show pdf.. But can I choose it before the file is completely download??

Comment: "But can I choose it before the file is completely download?" -- no.

Comment: @CommonsWare But if I try to open this [link](www.sp.camcom.it/pdf/Istruzioni-PDF-A.pdf) with android browser, before to start download the menù to choose the app appears..

Comment: Then contact the authors of your browser. There are dozens of browsers available for Android. The closest thing to "android browser" is the AOSP Browser app, and that's being phased out in favor of Chrome. But Samsung and others have their own browsers, in addition to perhaps the AOSP Browser app or Chrome, let alone users who install Firefox, etc. Different browsers may handle such downloads in different ways. Usually, though, it will either be before the download begins or after the download is completed (by the Downloads app), not mid-stream, as I interpreted your previous comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare as you can see in my quastion update, ther is a way to choose wich app use before download the pdf file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, after 2 days it works!

This is my solution:
pass `fileName.pdf` into url to download it and use these intent filter:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
  </intent-filter>
```